# match and replace 1 or 2 alpha characters and then a range of numeric characters up to a non alpha numeric

Tags: sed

I have a file (single column) with millions of records of IDs that Id like to simplify, removing non-alphanumeric characters.

```
cat test
U87391.1.79.>451
X81884.1.<830.1216,2579.3328,4330.4713
L14769.1.1.1785
Y07965.1.1090.2577
D63655.1.<1.>370
U11683.1.1.1641
X01094.1.5321.3672
X56015.1.1021.>1
U02039.1.1184.2263
KF761650.1.><d877
MN642084.1.2.345
JN641187<830.3033
JN641188.1.1.788
JN641190.2.1.238833
JN641192.2.333.<32
HQ544145.1
MZ748307.1
MZ748309.2
MZ748321.1000
```

It should look like this after the sed or similar command:

```
cat test.fixed
U87391
X81884
L14769
Y07965
D63655
U11683
X01094
X56015
U02039
KF761650
MN642084
JN641187
JN641188
JN641190
JN641192
HQ544145
MZ748307
MZ748309
MZ748321
```

I think I am close here, but am not quite able to code the proper regex. The issue is that some IDs have a single letter then numbers (e.g. `U87391`) while others have two letters followed by numeric characters (`HQ544145`).  So, im trying to match 1 or
2 alpha characters, then any number of numeric. Here is my script so far:

`cat test | gsed -n 's/.*\([A-Z]\{1,2\}[0-9]*\).*/\1/p'`   which produces this:

```
U87391
X81884
L14769
Y07965
D63655
U11683
X01094
X56015
U02039
F761650
N642084
N641187
N641188
N641190
N641192
Q544145
Z748307
Z748309
Z748321
```

Only the first alpha character is matched and kept for IDs that have 2 (e.g. `HQ544145.1` is changed to `Q544145` not `HQ544145`

I thought that this part of the regex woudl match 1 or 2 instances of an alpha character then match any number of numerics?  `([A-Z]\{1,2\}[0-9]*\)` but something isnt right. I am on MacOSX and thought gsed would have more regex functionality than sed -  when I try sed -E, i get errors. sed -r doesnt seem to work either.

Any help. is much appreciated!

LP

**UPDATE-** *left out potential cases to test* - IDs with numbers preceeding the alpha characters (e.g. `24874:MH119974.1.<1.>606` and
`24875:MT667246.1.5557.7102`) also occur. So, Matching any alphanumeric at the start of the row wont work.

Answer (score 2):

Match from a dot onwards and delete it:

```
cat test | sed 's/[^A-Z0-9].*//'
```

---

To also trim leading "ID" chars, eg for `24865:MT455790.1.<1.>655` to yield `MT455790`:

```
cat test | sed -E 's/^.*:|[^A-Z0-9].*//g'
```

Comment: nice. That is simple, but actually wont work for the broader use case. I realize that I left out one of the potential cases,  i.e. where a number could start the ID before the alpha characters:  ```24865:MT455790.1.<1.>655```. for this ID (and others like it), id like to simplify to ```MT455790```

Comment: @Bohemian sorry about leaving off other potential cases. The alpha part of the ID can start anywhere in the ID, with numbers sometimes preceeding it....

Answer (score 1):

This works with all the samples in your question.

```
sed -E 's/(.*[^A-Z])?([A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]*).*/\2/'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
grep -o '\<[A-Z]\{1,2\}[0-9]\+\>' file
```

This matches any word that has one or two A thru Z uppercase characters, followed by one or more 0 thru 9 characters.

An alternative using GNU sed:

```
sed -En '/\n/!s/\<[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]+\>/\n&\n/g;/^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]+\n/P;D' file
```

Comment: I like the grep answer! I didnt think to use it here. What are do the  "< " and ">" do?

Comment: @user95146 `\<` and `\>`  are start and end word boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution:

`cat test | sed -E 's/\d*[:]*(\w+).*/\1/'`